# Display notification based on sql query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to display a notification is a user has a value of NO in the table column "paid". It looks like everything is right to me... it's just not working. What am I doing wrong. (no errors, just not showing the notification. Yes, I know I should be using mysqli)

```
<!--Start Unpaid Notification-->
<?php

$unpaid_user = $_SESSION['loggedInUser'];

$get_unpaid = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM nflp_users WHERE userID = '$unpaid_user' AND paid = 'NO'")or die(mysql_error());


//Display Notification
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_unpaid)) {
if($row['paid'] == 'NO') {
echo '<div class="pm_notification">You have not paid yet. Please click <a href="https://paypal.com/">here</a> to pay.</div>';
echo '<br>';
 }
}
?>
<!--End Unpaid Notification-->
```

Comment: I don't see any issue, debugging time - echo all variables and return values

Comment: Have you tried var_dumping $get_unpaid. What is the result there? Could you add it here?

Comment: Here is the var_dump... hmmm not sure `resource(11) of type (mysql result) `

Comment: Do you have correct value in $unpaid_user variable?

Comment: Forgive my naivety, but if you know you should be using MySQLi, why aren't you?

Comment: Yes, correct values. If I run in phpmyadmin it brings a result or no result. Not sure what the deal is. I even took out the `$unpaid_user` variable and entered one manually, get the same results. I'm in the process of converting to MySQLi.

Comment: did you start the session?

Comment: add an else clause to echo out the value of $row['paid'] to see what values you are getting

Comment: `if(isset($_SESSION['loggedInUser'])){...} else{...}`

Comment: Side note, you don't really need to check `if($row['paid'] == 'NO')` because you've already included that in the query. Basically just need to check if the query returned anything.

Comment: @ me if you need me, closing this one.

Comment: The session is started further up on the page. Like I said, I take the $unpaid_user out of the picture and I get the same results.

Comment: First off, how many rows are you expecting to get according to the stored data? What do you get by doing the select in your db?

Comment: @MarkJones : What you get with :: `$get_unpaid = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM nflp_users");`

Comment: All it's supposed to do is query the database for the current user, and show a notification if the "paid" field says NO.

Comment: @MarkJones : To near down the error . Try it please.

Comment: I figured out the problem. See answer. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

I was using the wrong sql query. Instead of querying all columns with `*`, I needed to just query the `paid` column.

```
<!--Start Unpaid Notification-->
<?php

$unpaid_user = $_SESSION['loggedInUser'];

$get_unpaid = mysql_query("SELECT paid FROM nflp_users WHERE userID = '$unpaid_user'")or die(mysql_error());

//Display Notification
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_unpaid)) {
if($row['paid'] == 'NO') {
echo '<div class="pm_notification">You have not paid yet. Please click <a href="https://paypal.com/">here</a> to pay.</div>';
echo '<br>';
 }
}
?>
<!--End Unpaid Notification-->
```

Comment: and now you want to tell us, `*` replace with `paid` has solved the problem!

Comment: i can't see how that is possible, * returns all rows, but you don't use them so its irrelevant.

Comment: I think because I was returning all rows and using `paid = 'NO'` so it was returning blank. It confuses me as well but it works great now.